# How to fill a dataframe with values from another matching columns names and rows names in R?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have the following dataframes `DF1` and `DF2`. I am trying to fill `DF2` with values from the `Close` column in `DF1`. But it turns out that the output is zero when running the loop. Don't know what is wrong, but it seems it doesn't read the `Asset` column values.

DF1:

```
    Data        Asset   Close
1   1986-11-27  ABC 6   5.95
2   1986-12-01  ABC 6   5.90
3   1986-12-03  ABC 6   5.90
4   1986-12-04  ABC 6   5.90
5   1986-12-05  ABC 6   5.00
6   1986-12-08  ABC 6   5.00
7   1986-12-09  ABC 6   4.78
8   1986-10-31  ABC 8   3.90
9   1986-11-03  ABC 8   3.70
10  1986-11-04  ABC 8   3.70
.        .        .      .
.        .        .      .
```

DF2:

```
            ABC 6  ABC 8
1986-11-27   NA     NA
1986-12-01   NA     NA
1986-12-03   NA     NA
1986-12-04   NA     NA
1986-12-05   NA     NA
1986-12-08   NA     NA
1986-12-09   NA     NA
1986-12-10   NA     NA
1986-12-11   NA     NA
1986-12-12   NA     NA
    .        .      .
    .        .      .
```

```
for (i in 1:length(DF2))
  {
    for (m in 1:nrow(DF2))
    {
      for (n in 1:nrow(DF1))
        {
          if ((names(DF2[i]) == DF1[n,2]) & (row.names(DF2[m,0])==as.character(DF1[n,1])))
          {
            DF2[m,i] <- DF1[n,3]
          } else{DF2[m,i] <- 0}
        }
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
            ABC 6  ABC 8
1986-11-27   0      0
1986-12-01   0      0
1986-12-03   0      0
1986-12-04   0      0
1986-12-05   0      0
1986-12-08   0      0
1986-12-09   0      0
1986-12-10   0      0
1986-12-11   0      0
1986-12-12   0      0
    .        .      .
    .        .      .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to *reshape the data from long to wide format*.

This is a very common operation and questions have been asked and answered many times before, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/3817004).

However, just for demonstration, here is a collection of solutions which provide the expected result:

#### Base R

```
reshape(DF1, idvar = "Data", timevar = "Asset", v.names = "Close", direction = "wide")
```

> ```
>          Data Close.ABC 6 Close.ABC 8
> 1  1986-11-27        5.95          NA
> 2  1986-12-01        5.90          NA
> 3  1986-12-03        5.90          NA
> 4  1986-12-04        5.90          NA
> 5  1986-12-05        5.00          NA
> 6  1986-12-08        5.00          NA
> 7  1986-12-09        4.78          NA
> 8  1986-10-31          NA         3.9
> 9  1986-11-03          NA         3.7
> 10 1986-11-04          NA         3.7
> ```

#### `reshape2` package

```
reshape2::dcast(DF1, Data ~ Asset)
```

> ```
> Using Close as value column: use value.var to override.
>          Data ABC 6 ABC 8
> 1  1986-10-31    NA   3.9
> 2  1986-11-03    NA   3.7
> 3  1986-11-04    NA   3.7
> 4  1986-11-27  5.95    NA
> 5  1986-12-01  5.90    NA
> 6  1986-12-03  5.90    NA
> 7  1986-12-04  5.90    NA
> 8  1986-12-05  5.00    NA
> 9  1986-12-08  5.00    NA
> 10 1986-12-09  4.78    NA
> ```

#### `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(DF1), Data ~ Asset)
```

> ```
> Using 'Close' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
>           Data ABC 6 ABC 8
>  1: 1986-10-31    NA   3.9
>  2: 1986-11-03    NA   3.7
>  3: 1986-11-04    NA   3.7
>  4: 1986-11-27  5.95    NA
>  5: 1986-12-01  5.90    NA
>  6: 1986-12-03  5.90    NA
>  7: 1986-12-04  5.90    NA
>  8: 1986-12-05  5.00    NA
>  9: 1986-12-08  5.00    NA
> 10: 1986-12-09  4.78    NA
> ```

#### `tidyr` package

```
library(tidyr)
DF1 %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Asset, values_from = Close)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 3
>    Data       `ABC 6` `ABC 8`
>    <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>
>  1 1986-11-27    5.95    NA  
>  2 1986-12-01    5.9     NA  
>  3 1986-12-03    5.9     NA  
>  4 1986-12-04    5.9     NA  
>  5 1986-12-05    5       NA  
>  6 1986-12-08    5       NA  
>  7 1986-12-09    4.78    NA  
>  8 1986-10-31   NA        3.9
>  9 1986-11-03   NA        3.7
> 10 1986-11-04   NA        3.7
> ```

#### Data

```
DF1 <- as.data.frame(readr::read_table("rn    Data        Asset   Close
1   1986-11-27  ABC 6   5.95
2   1986-12-01  ABC 6   5.90
3   1986-12-03  ABC 6   5.90
4   1986-12-04  ABC 6   5.90
5   1986-12-05  ABC 6   5.00
6   1986-12-08  ABC 6   5.00
7   1986-12-09  ABC 6   4.78
8   1986-10-31  ABC 8   3.90
9   1986-11-03  ABC 8   3.70
10  1986-11-04  ABC 8   3.70", col_types = "_ccd"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want to achieve. A solution with `base R` is given as below:

```
DF2 <- cbind(DF2[1],sapply(names(DF2)[-1], 
                           function(v) DF1$Close[match(DF2$Date,subset(DF1,Asset==v)$Date)]))
```

such that

```
> DF2
         Date ABC 6 ABC 8
1  1986-11-27  5.95    NA
2  1986-12-01  5.90    NA
3  1986-12-03  5.90    NA
4  1986-12-04  5.90    NA
5  1986-12-05  5.00    NA
6  1986-12-08  5.00    NA
7  1986-12-09  4.78    NA
8  1986-12-10    NA    NA
9  1986-12-11    NA    NA
10 1986-12-12    NA    NA
```

**DATA**

```
DF1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
                                         1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1986-10-31", "1986-11-03", "1986-11-04", 
                                                                 "1986-11-27", "1986-12-01", "1986-12-03", "1986-12-04", "1986-12-05", 
                                                                 "1986-12-08", "1986-12-09"), class = "factor"), Asset = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ABC 6", "ABC 8"
                                                                                                                                     ), class = "factor"), Close = c(5.95, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 5, 5, 4.78, 
                                                                                                                                                                     3.9, 3.7, 3.7)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
DF2 <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:10, .Label = c("1986-11-27", 
                                                        "1986-12-01", "1986-12-03", "1986-12-04", "1986-12-05", "1986-12-08", 
                                                        "1986-12-09", "1986-12-10", "1986-12-11", "1986-12-12"), class = "factor"), 
                      "ABC 6" = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), "ABC 8" = c(NA, 
                                                                                   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                             -10L))
```